# Dynamically changed Open Graph properties aren't shown on Facebook

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, share, facebook-opengraph

I am using an Open Graph to make my website beautiful when sharing on Facebook. I have the following meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="url">
    <meta property="og:title" content="title">
    <meta property="og:image" content="img">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:description" content="desc">
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="908069756051947" />
```

And this works fine. Now I want to change it dynamically, so I have Facebook SDK included like this:

```
<script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId            : '908069756051947',
          autoLogAppEvents : true,
          xfbml            : true,
          version          : 'v3.1'
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

In body tags. And I change them dynamically like this (only when there is substring "id" in url):

```
FB.ui(
            {
              method: 'share_open_graph',
              action_type: 'og.shares',
              action_properties: JSON.stringify({
                object: {
                  'og:url': "new_url",
                  'og:title': "new_title",
                  'og:description': "new_desc",
                  'og:image': "new_img"
                }
              })
            }, 
            function(response) {

            }
        );
```

Now, what I need is, if "id" is included in URL and shared like that on Facebook, I want Facebook to display the newly generated properties, but instead, the old ones are shown. How to fix this?

Comment: _“And I change them dynamically like this”_ - that is not dynamically changing the meta tags, it is trying to overwrite the values used at the time of sharing. Facebook had disabled that a while ago for “normal” shares (part of the fight against fake news), and now it looks like they closed this “loophole” of sharing as an Open Graph action with modified values as well.

Comment: Unless you are posting to a _page_ that has claimed ownership of the content, Facebook does not want this to be possible any more, it gets abused too much. So you will have to create individual URLs that return the desired set of meta data directly when requested from the server, if you need to post/share like that.